# std::stringstream like a private variable in class

Tags: c++, class, std, stringstream

I want to use std::stringstream like a private variable in my class.
But i have an error "undeclared identifier".
PLease, explain why and get me advice how can i do this.

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::stringstream str;    
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: *"But i have an error"* is as useful as "my cat could be on fire". Please always include the complete error report, including burning cats and line numbers

Comment: @Zeta You're my hero. Too bad I didn't perceive your presence sooner around here. Your light yet useful and teaching sarcasm pleases me.

Comment: It's so demoralizing to see your downvotes. The question had been edited well. Moreover, It's solve my problem for the similar question. Yet, much snowball effect in SO... :-), You Shall have my first Upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you haven't included the proper header file. Also, don't forget the semicolon at the end of the class definition:

```
#include <sstream> // <== This is what you need for std::stringstream

class Test
{
private:
    std::stringstream str;    
}; // <== Don't forget the semicolon
```